# R split one column based on another

Tags: r, split, data-manipulation

I want to split a column based on another. I explain in the following.
here is part of my data:

```
brand    products
APPLE    IPHONE6SPlus_16G
APPLE    IPHONE6S_64G
APPLE    IPHONE6S_16G
APPLE    IPhone6_32G
APPLE    iPadAir2_64G
APPLE    iPadmini2_16G
APPLE    iPadmini4_64G
HTC      ONEX
Samsung  SamsungGalaxy
```

I want to split `brand` based on `Products`.  here is what I actually want.

```
brand       products
iPhone6S    IPHONE6SPlus_16G
iPhone6S    IPHONE6S_64G
iPhone6S    IPHONE6S_16G
iPhone6     IPhone6_32G
APPLE       iPadAir2_64G
APPLE       iPadmini2_16G
APPLE       iPadmini4_64G
HTC         ONEX
Samsung     SamsungGalaxy
```

I just want to split `APPLE` into three new(APPLE, iPhone6S, iPhone6) based on `products`. If the name in `products` contains *IPHONE6SPlus*, *IPHONE6S*, change `brand` to iPhone6S. If the name in `products` contains *IPhone6*, change `brand` to iPhone6. And the remainings do not change.

I think I can use `iflese` to do, but there are **size**(i.e. 16G, 64G, etc.) in `products` name.
How can I ignore these size and split the data.

Comment: You can use `grepl` to match the pattern i.e. `df1$brand[grepl("IPHONE6S", df1$products)] <- "IPHONE6S"`

Comment: It is not clear whether you have only a single pattern.  Try `v1 <- sub("^(.)(.)(.{5})(.).*", "\\L\\1\\U\\2\\L\\3\\U\\4", df1$products, perl = TRUE);df1$brand[v1=="iPhone6S"] <- v1[v1 == "iPhone6S"]`

Comment: can you explain `v1 <- sub("^(.)(.)(.{5})(.).*", "\\L\\1\\U\\2\\L\\3\\U\\4"", df1$products, perl = TRUE)`. Thanks

Comment: I posted a solution with some description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using a couple of methods.  Here, is one with `sub` and `==`

```
v1 <- sub("^(.)(.)(.{5})(.).*", "\\L\\1\\U\\2\\L\\3\\U\\4", df1$products, perl = TRUE)
df1$brand[v1=="iPhone6S"] <- v1[v1 == "iPhone6S"]
df1
#     brand         products
#1 iPhone6S IPHONE6SPlus_16G
#2 iPhone6S     IPHONE6S_64G
#3 iPhone6S     IPHONE6S_16G
#4    APPLE      IPhone6_32G
#5    APPLE     iPadAir2_64G
#6    APPLE    iPadmini2_16G
#7    APPLE    iPadmini4_64G
#8      HTC             ONEX
#9  Samsung    SamsungGalaxy
```

The `sub` matches the `pattern` of first element capture as a group (`(.)`) from the beginning of the string (`^`), followed by next element as another group, next 5 elements as third group (`(.{5})`), followed by another element as a group and the rest of the elements (`.*`).  In the replacement, we either change the case to lower (`\\L`) or upper (`\\U`) for the backreference of those groups (`\\1`)

---

Or an easier option is with `grepl`

```
df1$brand[grepl("IPHONE6S", df1$products)] <- "iPhone6S"
```

---

If the column have both lower and upper case characters, then it can be converted to either one of them using `tolower` or `toupper` and then do the processing

```
df1$brand[grepl("IPHONE6S", toupper(df1$products))] <- "iPhone6S"
```

---

Suppose we want to change multiple elements, this can be done with looping

```
nm1 <- c("IPAD", "IPHONE", "SAMSUNG")
for(j in nm1) df1$brand[grepl(j, toupper(df1$products))] <- j
df1
#   brand         products
#1  IPHONE IPHONE6SPlus_16G
#2  IPHONE     IPHONE6S_64G
#3  IPHONE     IPHONE6S_16G
#4  IPHONE      IPhone6_32G
#5    IPAD     iPadAir2_64G
#6    IPAD    iPadmini2_16G
#7    IPAD    iPadmini4_64G
#8     HTC             ONEX
#9 SAMSUNG    SamsungGalaxy
```

Comment: Can I ignore alphabet capitals and lower case letters in `products`? Also, can I igonre space(like: iPhone 6)?

Comment: @PeterChen  I am not getting your question. FOr example, `IPHONE6SPlus_16G`, suppose we ignore upper case and lower case letter, then only 6, 16 and `_` remains

Comment: For example, **IPHONE6SPlus** and **iphone6splus** is the same

Comment: @PeterChen  You can remove all the spaces with `gsub("\\s+", "", df1$products)` or if we wanted to ignore it

Comment: @PeterChen That you can do this either converting them to lower or upper i.e. `tolower(df1$products)` or `toupper(df1$products)`

Comment: maybe u can add these to ur answer. Thanks. it's awesome.

Comment: can I list name of `products` based on `brand`? like `if(brand == 'APPLE) unique(products)`. I know this is not true. any suggestion?

Comment: @PeterChen If you want to do this for each unique element, you can loop through the elements and do the `grepl` i.e. `nm1 <- c("APPLE", "IPHONE6S"); for(j in nm1) df1$brand[grepl(j, toupper(df1$products))] <- j`

Answer (score 1):

'Dirty' solution but I hope it helps :)

```
x <- c('IPHONE6SPlus','IPHONE6S')
b$new <- grepl(paste(x, collapse = "|"), b$products)
b$brand[b$new==TRUE] <- "Iphone6S"
b$new <- NULL
y <- c('IPhone6')
b$new <- grepl(paste(y, collapse = "|"), b$products)
b$brand[b$new==TRUE] <- "Iphone6"
b$new <- NULL

     brand         products
1 Iphone6S IPHONE6SPlus_16G
2 Iphone6S     IPHONE6S_64G
3 Iphone6S     IPHONE6S_16G
4  Iphone6      IPhone6_32G
5    APPLE     iPadAir2_64G
6    APPLE    iPadmini2_16G
7    APPLE    iPadmini4_64G
8      HTC             ONEX
9  Samsung    SamsungGalaxy
```